# How can I calculate the volume of a Sphere in $R^n$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion

The radius of the sphere is the set of the Points $\{x\mid r^2=|x|^2\}$, where the sphere is in $R^n$. We describe the volume as $V_n(r)$, How can I prove the 
characteristic of the sphere, that:

$$V_n(r)=\int_{-r}^r\mathrm dx\, V_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\right),\; V_n(\lambda r)=\lambda^n V_n(r)$$

If $V_0=1$, how can I program the recursive relationship

$$V_n(r)=V_{n-1}(r)\,r\int_0^1\mathrm du\, u^{-\frac12}(1-u)^\frac{n-1}{2}$$

Comment: Your first question seems more about the math, than about the *Mathematica* software package. What have you tried for the second one?

Comment: Is this question about the software produce [*Mathematica*](http://wri.com)?  If yes, what have you tried so far?  This may be useful reading: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/27-applying-functions-repeatedly.html

Comment: I just want to learn how to solve math problem with Mathematica

Answer (score 6):

Your integral can be rewritten as `Gamma functions`, the result is the same.

```
Integrate[u^(-1/2) (1 - u)^((n - 1)/2), {u, 0, 1}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[π] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/Gamma[1 + n/2], Re[n] > -1]`

Obviously the `ConditionalExpression` is always true, so use this in the recurrence relation.

```
RSolve[v[n] == 
  v[n - 1] r (Sqrt[π] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/Gamma[1 + n/2], v[n], n]
```

Apply the result to a symbol:

```
vol[n_] := (π^(n/2) r^(-1 + n) C[1])/(n Gamma[n/2])
```

We need to solve this for your initial condition

```
vol2[n_] := 
  Evaluate[vol[n] /. Solve[Limit[vol[n], n -> 0] == 1, C[1]]]
vol2[3]
```

> `{(4 π r^3)/3}`

As expected.

Comment: very helpful!thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer, but it can be simplified further by adding the initial condition `v[0]==1` to the `RSolve`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement volume of n-ball using your recursion formula like this:

```
f[n_] := Integrate[u^(-1/2) (1 - u)^((n - 1)/2), {u, 0, 1}]
v[r_, num_] := 
 NestList[{# [[1]] r f[#[[2]]], #[[2]] + 1} &, {1, 1}, num][[All, 1]]
```

For example: `v[r, 7]`:

```
{1, 2 r, π r^2, (4 π r^3)/3, (π^2 r^4)/2, (
 8 π^2 r^5)/15, (π^3 r^6)/6, (16 π^3 r^7)/105}
```